# How to set the primaryConnectionString for Azure servicebus using cli?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

How to set the primaryConnectionString for Azure servicebus using az cli? Would this work?

> az servicebus namespace authorization-rule update --set
> primaryConnectionString "connection string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

If you want to set your own key as a PrimaryKey, it is not possiable.

**Original:**

Please use the code below:

```
az servicebus namespace authorization-rule keys renew --key PrimaryKey --name xxx --namespace-name xxxxxx --resource-group xxxxxx --subscription xxxxxx
```

And please refer to this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/namespace/authorization-rule/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az_servicebus_namespace_authorization_rule_keys_renew

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to renew the PrimaryKey but I should be able to set my own key as a PrimaryKey? Is that doable?

Comment: No you can't. The key is assigned automatically by Azure.

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan No, it is not possible. I have updated my answer.